# including <functional> and <memory> headers causes errors when compiling in VS2015 with platform tool settings "Microsoft CodeGen v140_clang_c2"

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

I have compiled and ran [this](https://ideone.com/r05gT4) code in clang (also in [gcc6.3](https://ideone.com/pz1z37)) and they all work fine.

Also in my visual studio 2015, I have compiled with the following Platformtoolsets.

- Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)
- Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)

both compile fine.

but when i use the toolset,

- Visual Studio 2015 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v140_clang_c2)

[image]

I get the following errors

[image]

The issue seems to be happen when i include the memory and functional headers.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
```

any idea why this is happening? and how can i avoid it?

Comment: Find the "RTTI" (Run Time Type Information) option under the C++ compiler options and change it to "Use RTTI".  (Going from memory, those labels might not be exact.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm , thanks alot! that did the trick.  it was under Property Pages->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language. changed the Enable RunTime Type Information to Yes(-frtti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 1201ProgramAlarm mentioned in the comments i had to turn the enable runtime type information in properties. 
(for visual studio 2015) in property pages, expand the Configuration Properties->C/C++ then select Language.
Change the **No (-fno-rtti)** to **Yes (-frtti)** 
[image]

Comment: The clang shared ptr destruction type eraser uses RTTI as part of its implementation is the cause, I believe.